# Fill background of GIMP by a pattern

Tags: gimp

I want to fill background layer of my image in GIMP by custom patterns, but GIMP only has several patterns saved in GIMP's pattern's directory.

Where is that directory or is there any way to import my custom pattern?

My Ubuntu version is 17.10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Place the images you want to use as patterns in the `~/.gimp-x.x/patterns` (`x.x` stands for GIMP version, e.g. `2.8`) directory.

Comment: thank you it is working and doesn't need  sudo :)

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution you must open your terminal and write this

```
sudo cp <pattern-address> /usr/share/gimp/2.0/patterns/
```

maybe the 2.0/ has a different name in your computer

if any body has a better solution i glad to read that